# Form Switch Component and Default Values doesn't showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hook-form

I'm working with React JS and GraphQL, and I'm creating this table component. Inside the table, there are many switch components, and their values are coming from the API.

[image]

And also, here's the respons from API :

```
{
  "data": {
    "getMenuPermissionsList": [
      {
        "idMenu": "1",
        "menuName": "Dashboard",
        "permissions": [
          {
            "add": false,
            "view": true,
            "delete": false,
            "modify": false,
            "export": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "idMenu": "4",
        "menuName": "Konfigurasi",
        "permissions": []
      },
      {
        "idMenu": "24",
        "menuName": "Layanan Operasional",
        "permissions": []
      },
      {
        "idMenu": "7",
        "menuName": "Layanan Pasien",
        "permissions": [
          {
            "add": false,
            "view": true,
            "delete": false,
            "modify": false,
            "export": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Problem**

I am using react-hook-form library for receiving default values from permissions that will be render to switch component :

```
const history = useHistory();
  const { data: getMenuPerms, loading: getMenuPermsLoading, error: getMenuPermsError } = useQuery(GET_MENU_PERMISSIONS_LOGGED_IN);
  const initialValues = getMenuPerms?.getMenuPermissionsLoggedin;

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Tambah Group Role";
  }, []);

  const { register, handleSubmit, control, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      perms: initialValues?.flatMap((menu) =>
        menu?.subMenu.flatMap((perm) =>
          perm?.permissions.map((val) => ({
            view: val.view,
            add: val.add,
            modify: val.modify,
            delete: val.delete,
            export: val.export,
            permission: val.permission
          }))
        )
      )
    }
  });
  
  const { fields } = useFieldArray({
    name: "perms",
    control
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`permswatch: ${watch("perms")}`);
  }, [watch]);
```

And then, the initialValues and fields becomes value for TableRole props.

```
<TableRole
      checked={initialValues}
      fields={fields}
      register={register}
 />
```

And the result comes like this :

[image]

Here is the complete code :

formKontrolHakAksesTambah.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Card, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FormCreateGroup } from "../../../component/GrupDanHakAkses/Form";
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { CREATE_USER_GROUP, ASSIGN_PERMS } from "../../../gql/mutation";
import { GET_ALL_USER_GROUP, GET_MENU_PERMISSIONS_LOGGED_IN } from "../../../gql/query";
import { FaSave } from "react-icons/fa";

import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Loading } from "../../../component/Common";
import styles from "./formAkses.module.scss";
import { TableRole } from "../../../component/GrupDanHakAkses/Table";
import Divider from "../../../component/Common/Page/Divider";
import ButtonSecondary from "../../../component/Common/Button/ButtonSecondary";
import { useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import ButtonPrimary from "../../../component/Common/Button/ButtonPrimary";

const FormKontrolDanHakAksesTambah = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { data: getMenuPerms, loading: getMenuPermsLoading, error: getMenuPermsError } = useQuery(GET_MENU_PERMISSIONS_LOGGED_IN);
  const initialValues = getMenuPerms?.getMenuPermissionsLoggedin;

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Tambah Group Role";
  }, []);

  const { register, handleSubmit, control, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      perms: initialValues?.flatMap((menu) =>
        menu?.subMenu.flatMap((perm) =>
          perm?.permissions.map((val) => ({
            view: val.view,
            add: val.add,
            modify: val.modify,
            delete: val.delete,
            export: val.export,
            permission: val.permission
          }))
        )
      )
    }
  });
  
  const { fields } = useFieldArray({
    name: "perms",
    control
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`permswatch: ${watch("perms")}`);
  }, [watch]);

  // state for input form group and switches
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    groupId: "",
    groupName: "",
    groupDesc: "",
  });

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue({
      ...value,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  
  const [createUserGroup, { loading: loadingCreateUserGroup }] = useMutation(
    CREATE_USER_GROUP,
    {
      onCompleted: () => {
        history.push("/konfigurasi/grup-dan-hak-akses-pengguna");
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        console.error(err.message);
      },
    }
  );

  const [assignPermission, { loading: assignPermsLoading }] = useMutation(
    ASSIGN_PERMS,
    {
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      },
    }
  );

  if (loadingCreateUserGroup || assignPermsLoading)
    return (
      <>
        <Loading />
      </>
    );

  const handleSubmitGroupBaru = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (
      value.groupId === "" ||
      value.groupName === "" ||
      value.groupDesc === ""
    ) {
      // Menampilkan pesan error jika ada field yang kosong
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "error",
        title: "Silakan lengkapi semua field",
      });
      return;
    }

    try {
      // Membuat promise untuk mutasi createUserGroup
      const createGroupPromise = createUserGroup({
        variables: {
          input: {
            groupId: value.groupId,
            groupName: value.groupName,
            groupDesc: value.groupDesc,
          },
        },
        awaitRefetchQueries: true,
        refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_ALL_USER_GROUP }, "getAllUserGroup"],
      });

      // Menunggu hasil promise mutasi createUserGroup
      const {
        data: {
          createUserGroup: { groupId },
        },
      } = await createGroupPromise;

      // Membuat promise untuk mutasi assignPermission
      const assignPermissionPromise = assignPermission({
        variables: {
          input: {
            groupId: groupId,
            permissionCodes: []
          },
        },
      });

      // Menunggu hasil promise mutasi assignPermission
      await assignPermissionPromise;

      Swal.fire({
        icon: "success",
        title: "Akun Grup berhasil ditambahkan",
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "error",
        title: err.message,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className={`${styles.FormAksi}`}>
        <Container className={`${styles.container}`}>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Card className={`${styles.customCard}`}>
                <Card.Title className={`${styles.customCardHeader}`}>
                  <p className="text-uppercase base-lg text-semi-bold">
                    Informasi Grup Akun
                  </p>
                </Card.Title>
                <Card.Body>
                  <FormCreateGroup onChange={onChange} value={value} />
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Card className="border-0 mt-5">
                <Card.Title>
                  <p className="text-uppercase base-lg text-semi-bold mt-2 mx-2">
                    Kontrol Akses
                  </p>
                </Card.Title>
                <Card.Body>
                  { getMenuPermsLoading && <Loading/> }
                  { getMenuPermsError && <p>{getMenuPermsError.message}</p> }
                  <TableRole
                    checked={initialValues}
                    fields={fields}
                    register={register}
                  />
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>

        <Divider className="my-3" />

        <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
          <ButtonSecondary
            variant="solid"
            wider="true"
            onClick={handleSubmitGroupBaru}
            className="mt-5"
          >
            {" "}
            <FaSave className="mx-2" /> SIMPAN PERUBAHAN
          </ButtonSecondary>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default FormKontrolDanHakAksesTambah;
```

TableRole.js :

```
import React, { Fragment, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useFieldArray, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function TableRole({ checked, register, fields }) {
  const tableHeader = [
    "No",
    "Menu",
    "Sub Menu",
    "Lihat",
    "Tambah",
    "Ubah",
    "Hapus",
    "Export"
  ];

  return (
    <Table className="table-responsive">
      <thead
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#ECEFF1" }}
        className="txt-blue-grey-700 base-md text-bold"
      >
        <tr>
          {tableHeader.map((header, index) => (
            <th
              key={index}
              className="txt-blue-grey-700 base-md text-bold text-center"
              style={{ padding: "0.75rem" }}
            >
              {header}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody className="text-center">
        {checked?.map((row) => (
            <React.Fragment key={row.id}>
              <RoleRow
                fields={fields}
                register={register}
                row={row}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

const RoleRow = ({ row, register, fields, defaultValues }) => (
    <>
      <tr>
        <td rowSpan={row.subMenu.length + 1}>{row.idMenu}</td>
        <td rowSpan={row.subMenu.length + 1}>{row.menuName}</td>
      </tr>
      {
          row.subMenu.map((subMenuItem) => (
            <>
              <tr key={subMenuItem.idMenu}>
                <td>{subMenuItem.menuName}</td>
                {
                  fields?.map((value) => (
                      <PermissionCheckbox value={value} register={register} fields={fields} />
                    ))
                }
              </tr>
            </>
          ))
        }
    </>
);

const PermissionCheckbox = ({ fields, register, value }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {
        fields.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Fragment key={`perms.${index}.permission`}>
                <td>
                  <Form.Check
                    id={`lihat-${item.id}`}
                    type="switch"
                    value={value}
                    {...register(`perms.${index}.view`)}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Form.Check
                    id={`tambah-${item.id}`}
                    type="switch"
                    {...register(`perms.${index}.add`)}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Form.Check
                    id={`ubah-${item.id}`}
                    type="switch"
                    {...register(`perms.${index}.modify`)}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Form.Check
                    id={`hapus-${item.id}`}
                    type="switch"
                    {...register(`perms.${index}.delete`)}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Form.Check
                    id={`export-${item.id}`}
                    type="switch"
                    {...register(`perms.${index}.export`)}
                  />
                </td>
            </Fragment>
          )
        })
      }
    </>
  );
};
```

**Question**

How can I handle default values from the parent and pass the data to the child component (TableRole) using react-hook-form? Additionally, how can the TableRole component read the data that is coming from the API ?